# JQuery Mobile - how to use it for ONLY swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mobile, swipe

I am having huge problems with the jquery mobile pack, it broke my entire page by making links go to ajax and showing the loading div etc. I tried fixing them all and I somehow managed it with tons of excess code (I  don't know what part exactly hid the loading part and which part undid the ajax).

Basically JQuery mobile made a mess of my page, and all I need is the swipe event, I found the github repository of jquery mobile ([Here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/js)), but I honestly have no idea which parts to take so I can use the swipe event.

I know people want code, but there is no problem in my code here, JQuery mobile simply wants to open all links in ajax, and because I am using bootstrap and I don't use JQuery mobile for anything else but swipes, I won't be pasting anything.

If anyone can tell me which parts I need to take/modify to make it work that would be awesome.

I tried by only copying the events/touch.js but it didn't work.

Comment: it will make a mess of you of you page if the only thing you want out of the JQM framework is swipe. you said you don't have to provide any code because its all ok. However you will need to provide as to what you are using Swipe for and why you require JQM for that. Assuming you want to use JQM swipe to pages your better off checking ISCROLL 5. here is an old demo using iscrol 2 ... http://vimeo.com/16658890

Comment: I am only using swipe for a custom gallery. If you really want the code then here it is, this is the only part im using:
$("#mobile_desno, #mobile_levo").on("swiperight", function() {
                //MY CODE
                });
And of coure the same event for swiping to left (previous image).

Comment: If you think its stupid then just make your own swipe function. Its not very hard and you wont need to ask questions regarding JQM. Also, you would just need to get ahold of the swipe function and bind it to the DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I've had the same issue today and found a little very practical solution with this little snippet called [swipe-detect.js](https://gist.github.com/AlexEmashev/ee8302b5036b01362f63dab35948401f)
, which does just that and nothing else.

You can use it like that (all credits to Alexander Emashev):

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.swipeDetector = function(options) {
    // States: 0 - no swipe, 1 - swipe started, 2 - swipe released
    var swipeState = 0;
    // Coordinates when swipe started
    var startX = 0;
    var startY = 0;
    // Distance of swipe
    var pixelOffsetX = 0;
    var pixelOffsetY = 0;
    // Target element which should detect swipes.
    var swipeTarget = this;
    var defaultSettings = {
      // Amount of pixels, when swipe don't count.
      swipeThreshold: 70,
      // Flag that indicates that plugin should react only on touch events.
      // Not on mouse events too.
      useOnlyTouch: false
    };

    // Initializer
    (function init() {
      options = $.extend(defaultSettings, options);
      // Support touch and mouse as well.
      swipeTarget.on("mousedown touchstart", swipeStart);
      $("html").on("mouseup touchend", swipeEnd);
      $("html").on("mousemove touchmove", swiping);
    })();

    function swipeStart(event) {
      if (options.useOnlyTouch && !event.originalEvent.touches) return;

      if (event.originalEvent.touches) event = event.originalEvent.touches[0];

      if (swipeState === 0) {
        swipeState = 1;
        startX = event.clientX;
        startY = event.clientY;
      }
    }

    function swipeEnd(event) {
      if (swipeState === 2) {
        swipeState = 0;

        if (
          Math.abs(pixelOffsetX) > Math.abs(pixelOffsetY) &&
          Math.abs(pixelOffsetX) > options.swipeThreshold
        ) {
          // Horizontal Swipe
          if (pixelOffsetX < 0) {
            swipeTarget.trigger($.Event("swipeLeft.sd"));
            console.log("Left");
          } else {
            swipeTarget.trigger($.Event("swipeRight.sd"));
            console.log("Right");
          }
        } else if (Math.abs(pixelOffsetY) > options.swipeThreshold) {
          // Vertical swipe
          if (pixelOffsetY < 0) {
            swipeTarget.trigger($.Event("swipeUp.sd"));
            console.log("Up");
          } else {
            swipeTarget.trigger($.Event("swipeDown.sd"));
            console.log("Down");
          }
        }
      }
    }

    function swiping(event) {
      // If swipe don't occuring, do nothing.
      if (swipeState !== 1) return;

      if (event.originalEvent.touches) {
        event = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
      }

      var swipeOffsetX = event.clientX - startX;
      var swipeOffsetY = event.clientY - startY;

      if (
        Math.abs(swipeOffsetX) > options.swipeThreshold ||
        Math.abs(swipeOffsetY) > options.swipeThreshold
      ) {
        swipeState = 2;
        pixelOffsetX = swipeOffsetX;
        pixelOffsetY = swipeOffsetY;
      }
    }

    return swipeTarget; // Return element available for chaining.
  };
})(jQuery);

// Showcase
$("document").ready(function() {
  var message = $(".message");
  $(".swipe-detector")
    .swipeDetector()
    .on("swipeLeft.sd swipeRight.sd swipeUp.sd swipeDown.sd", function(event) {
      if (event.type === "swipeLeft") {
        message.text("Swipe Left");
      } else if (event.type === "swipeRight") {
        message.text("Swipe Right");
      } else if (event.type === "swipeUp") {
        message.text("Swipe Up");
      } else if (event.type === "swipeDown") {
        message.text("Swipe Down");
      }
    });
});
```

```css
    * {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      color: #4e84ba;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(40, 127, 214, 0.18);
    }
    
    .swipe-detector {
      width: 350px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: #52a9e8;
      margin: 65px auto 0;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px rgba(101, 166, 201, 0.34);
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center;
    }
    
    .message {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #ffffff;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
      
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Simple swipe jQuery plugin</h1>
  
   <div class="swipe-detector">
     <span class="message">Use touch or mouse to swipe.</span>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate page without using `ajax`  then you should add tag `rel=external`
Or `data-ajax="false"`
you can find more information for Jquery mobile  [HERE](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html)

**EDITED**

I have Another solution but I pesonally not prefer but I also having same issue before so I tried this solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("a").click(function (){

window.top.location = $(this).attr("href");
return false;
});

});
```

Try this I hope its work for you too..

this function will force change document location when user click on any `Hyperlink`

Comment: As I said I've already found those links, but adding data-ajax="false" is stupid IMO, as the global command people were giving (here on stackoverflow) did not work for me.

So, I still just want to know how to only take the "swipe" event from JQuery mobile WITHOUT anything else.